# Multiple custom request header is not working in C#

Tags: c#, http, request

I have to add an image in request body with some request header contains image name,foldername and imageid like that , but when i add one header with an image is working good but with multiple headers it shows error what i miss

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) comes very handy in debugging http.

Comment: If you are adding headers with same key multiple times, it will throw error, you need to handle that.

Comment: No i am adding 1. imageID 2. UserID 3.ImageName